# Backspace key doesn't trigger ng-change / ng-keyup in angular 1.5 it deletes the last character in a textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Thank you in advance for any advice.  I have been banging my head on the wall with this one for a bit.  So far I have tried to use ng-change, ng-keyup, and ng-keypress.

HTML

```
<input type="password" ng-model="newPass" id="passwd" ng-keyup="validatePassword()"/>
```

Controller

```
$scope.validatePassword = function () {
        var onecap = false;
        var onenum = false;
        var eightchars = false;

        if ($scope.newPass.match(/^(?=.*[A-Z])/)) {
            $scope.oneCap = true;
        } else {
            $scope.oneCap = false;
        }
        if ($scope.newPass.match(/^(?=.*\d)/)) {
            $scope.oneNum = true;
        } else {
            $scope.oneNum = false;
        }
        if ($scope.newPass.match(/^[A-Za-z\d$@$!$#$^$($)$_$+%*?&]{8,}$/)) {
            $scope.eightChars = true;
        } else {
            $scope.eightChars = false;
        }

        $scope.validated = onecap && onenum && eightchars;
    };
```

For whatever reason, the 'delete / backspace' works and each scope variable is updated no problem, unless the delete key is deleting the last character in the textbox.

I do realize I can use a single string to test the password requirements; I have them separated to show the user what part of their password is lacking.

Comment: does both delete and backspace not work in that condition, or just backspace key.

Comment: Sorry I meant backspace only.  On my mac keyboard backspace is labeled "delete".

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup I'm not sure if this is the issue, the keyup method works fine with the delete key here. Have you done any logging to see what else may be going on?

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Yes I have, I have tried console.log() to get some more info.  I get true and false printed on every keyup event, except the last backspace; it never fires.  In fact, I am doing the exact same thing on a different page, and controller...works just fine.

Comment: Wait, just got another hint.  On the final backspace, I get a console error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined.  I am guessing it is trying to regex a blank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by blocking the match of an undefined variable to a regex.

```
if ($scope.newPass !== undefined) {
  validatePassword();
} else {
  return false;
}
```